# material-table react table header title

Tags: material-table

Could you please share your thoughts on how to override the material-table header title dynamically.

Example :

```
 const [columns, setColumns] = React.useState([
 { title: variable, field:'test_id },
```

I need to dynamically replace the variable value from the state value.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you directly replace *variable* with the name of your state value like this:

```
<MaterialTable
                     options={{
                        filtering: true,
                        search: true
                      }}
                      title="Products"
                      columns={
                          [
                        { title: columns, field: 'test_id', type: 'numeric', editable: 'never' },
```